# How to resolve this error - " One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try refreshing"? in Odoo v8?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Whenever I try to create an employee record in Human Resources, when I click Save, the above error occurs.

I checked in the database for any kind of ir-regularities and found that  I have attached the screenshot.

[image: Error image]

[image: Database error]

As in the database error, the Autoincrement ID has been skipped as I have noticed.
Anyone with a clear insight on this, kindly suggest with what can be done. It would really grateful. Thanks

Comment: Logout and login will fix this issue

Comment: Did you made any customization then please put it in question instead of db screen shot.

Comment: Dachi Darchiashvili - No it did not solve the issue in such way

Comment: Emipro Technologies, No customization has been done in the code point of view.

Comment: My guess is that there's a foreign key automatically set on employee creation in which the corresponding reference doesn't exist on the other table

Comment: @danidee, yes most probably i am doubting on the database aspect itself as you said.

Comment: Are you sure, there are no custom modules installed? The form isn't looking like the original, for example the smart buttons are always upper right corner.

Comment: @CZoellner, There are custom modules installed in addition to HR module part, As a matter of fact, that custom module was installed long back say 4 months, for that long time everything was proper, but in recent weeks, the error has started occuring after some data mismatch I feel.

Comment: @Emipro Technologies ,I meant no recent customization on code has been done.

Comment: @ShravyaShetty: It could be, that this custom module is defining a record for defaults. First try to update that module. And if you have access to the code, try to find the mistake there.

Comment: CZoellner, So you mean to say the problem may be from custom module and not of any data mismatch in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am answering the question,

There was a custom module which I was not aware of(other than my custom module) and that was installed. UNinstalling it removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database if you can, and re install your module and try again.

Comment: ..Re-Installing can be done, but as it is a set instance and database, I dont want things to be done again. If things does not work, your suggestion will be the only solution.